# Nested for loop in 'lists' and 'iterators'

Tags: python, list, iterator, nested-loops

I have these two lists

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [10,20,30]
```

I use this nested for loop to access all possible pairs:

```
for a in l1:
    for b in l2:
        print(a,b)
```

I get the following expected result:

```
1 10
1 20
1 30
2 10
2 20
2 30
3 10
3 20
3 30
```

But if I convert l1 and l2 to iterators, I get a different result and I can't access to all of the pairs:

```
l1=iter(l1)
l2=iter(l2)

for a in l1:
    for b in l2:
        print(a,b)

1 10
1 20
1 30
```

I can't understand the difference between these two code snippets. Why the iterators generate this result?

Comment: Once you've consumed the iterator, its done. No more values for you. After the first `for b in l2:` the well is dry.

Comment: I know this doesn't *look* like a duplicate, but that's the closest match I can easily find for this common problem. Sequence iterators created by `iter` have the same relevant behaviour as file iterators created by `open`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel -Actually... files can be rewound (e.g., `file.seek(0)`). They are a counter example. `iter()` itself doesn't care which type of iterator you get. `list_iterator` can't be rewound, file can.

Comment: They *can*, but the point is about the specific style of iteration in play.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel- Yes this is because reader objects are iterators, just like file object returned by open().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l2=iter(l2)
```

This creates an iterator out of `l2`. An iterator can only be iterated through **once**. After that, the interator is finished. If you wanted to iterate over `l2` again, you'd need to create another iterator from it.

```
for a in l1:
    for b in l2:
        print(a,b)
```

This will try to iterate over `l2` - once for each item in `l1`. If there are more than 1 items in `l1`, that won't work - because the `l2` iterator is already exhausted after the first iteration.

So you need something like this:

```
l1 = iter(l1)

for a in l1:
    l2_iter = iter(l2)
    for b in l2_iter:
        print(a,b)
```

Which would do what you expect.